# Does brief really mean short?

Tags: word-meaning

There are this books called

> a brief guide to writing academic arguments
>
> a brief guide to writing from readings
>
> a brief guide to business classics

as far as I know brief means a piece of writing that doesn't contain too many words

how can a book be brief?

Comment: writing academics is not used. Do you mean: A Brief Guide to Academic Writing? A guide is not necessarily long.

Comment: "how can a book be brief?" Compared to what? A 100 page summary of a 1000 page book could be considered "brief".

Comment: @lambie it was academic arguments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Brief" is a relative term. These books consider themselves to be short when compared with their alternatives.  "A Guide to Business Classics" could be a very long book.

Adding "Brief" to the title of a book, especially a howto or self-help book, is a common way to make the book seem less intimidating.

Comment: shouldn't it be briefer if it meant that way?. After putting more thought on it. I've come with this.  A subject X has 15 books. So a brief guide of X would be 1 book.   And if subject Y has 2 books. Then a brief guide of it would be a small booklet with few pages. What say?

Comment: I wouldn't try to overthinking marketing tactics.  "Brief" is simply a word put into the title to make the book seem more inviting to people who don't have a lot of time...it is not necessarily an accurate description of how long the book is.